# Eloquent many-to-many sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent to talk to my MySql database. I have a table of `teams` that has a many-to-many relationship with `tasks` via `tasks_teams`. `tasks` has a column called `points`. When teams complete tasks, they earn points.

I want to give the Team object a method to return the total points that team has earned. The SQL for this query is this:

```
SELECT SUM(points) FROM tasks_teams, tasks WHERE
    team_id = 1
AND tasks_teams.task_id = tasks.id;
```

This is my `Team` model:

```
class Team extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function tasks () {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'Task', 'tasks_teams');
    }
}
```

I want to add this method to `Team`, but it doesn't work:

```
public function points() {
    return $this->tasks->sum('points');
}
```

but I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sum() in [...]/Models/Team.php on line 19

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Found a [potential hint at the Laravel Forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=62003#p62003) (thanks bobodan!), tried it and it worked.

My solution:

```
public function points() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'Task', 'tasks_teams' )->sum('points');
}
```